# MonoTouch.Dialog: Dismissing a Keyboard

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Using the Reflection API to auto generate a UI.

How can I dismiss the keyboard when the user selects a new field, or if they choose a field which generates a new view to pick from. In the later case, when the user returns to the first screen, the old keyboard is still there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UIView.EndEditing(bool force);
```

The above will hide the keyboard for you without needing to know who the first responder is. I haven't done much with the reflection API but you should be able to call that on the view when an element is selected.

[Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) -- endEditing:

Answer (score 5):

Clarification for those initially struggling with the MonoDialog portion of the question:

The EndEditing method is not available on DialogViewControllers objects directly (who inherit from UITableViewControllers).  You should be calling EndEditing(bool) on the View of a DialogViewController and not trying to call EndEditing(bool) on the actual DialogViewController itself.

For clarification:

DialogViewController dc;
dc.View.EndEditing(true);

Note:
UIView objects include the EndEditing(bool) method, but UITableViewControllers do not inherit from UIView so the EndEditing method is not available on the controller itself.  UITableViewControllers contain a view object, call EndEditing on that view object.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ResignFirstResponder method. This one should help you I guess.