# Monotouch Hide Keyboard when Navbar is tapped using MonoTouch.Dialog

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am currently using this code to hide the keyboard in a monotouch iOS application when something outside the input elements are tapped.

```
 var tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer ();

 tap.AddTarget (() =>{

    dvc.View.EndEditing (true);

 });

 dvc.View.AddGestureRecognizer (tap);
```

However, I would like to hide the keyboard when the user taps the top Navbar as well. I have seen this in other apps. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to override `TouchesEnded` in your `UIViewController`.

This will give you any touch event inside the entire controller.

Then do something like this if you need ignore touches in a certain view:

```
public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);

    if (evt.TouchesForView(viewYouWantToIgnore) == null) {
        //Dismiss your keyboard here
    }
}
```

Comment: The views where I need this are DialogViewControllers, not UIViewControllers. Also, when I use it with a UIViewController, it still does not register a tap on the navbar.

Comment: You need to do this on the `UINavigationController` containing your inner view controller.  Since you are using `MonoTouch.Dialog` though, I don't know if they expose a way to do that.

Comment: Just checking, have you tried overriding this on your `DialogViewController`?

Comment: Yeah, no go. Nothing even seems to trigger the event.

Comment: This question seems to allude to that as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824092/monotouch-dialog-dismissing-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-in-dialogviewcontroll